# Fastest Continual Cycle Detection

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

I'm trying to build a directed graph implementation that I can add and delete nodes/edges from, and I can query whether any node participates in a cycle. By participate I mean that there exists a path from that node back to itself. Right now, whenever I query a single node, I have to run DFS on that node, and if I can reach the node again, then I return. However, I want to expand my query function by allowing for the user to query multiple nodes at once, so I want to use something more sophisticated than simply running DFS multiple times. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: How many nodes does the graph have/is expected to have? There are some adjacency matrix tricks that could be of use if the graph isn't too large. You could also search for the [strongly connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) in your graph - as long as a node is within a SCC that has more than one node, it is a part of a cycle. (As long as you consider a cycle of a length 2 suitable for your case.)

Comment: I've been looking into an iterative version of Tarjan's to partially look for SCCs. For each node that I want to query, I determine whether it is part of one of the found SCCs during this query. Between different queries I clear my SCCs. Does this sound like it could work?

Comment: Yes, is looks like something that could work. You can't get better than O(|V| + |E|) anyways and Tarjan's will give you your answer within this bound. Rest would be just considering use-case specific optimizations depending on expected properties of the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anybody out there, I ended up using Tarjan's Strongly Connected Component algorithm. I kept track of which nodes were visited during each run through of the algorithm, and if I queried a node that was already visited, I would skip that node. Eventually, for a single query, I visited each node in the graph at most once.